# What is this kind of javascript programming in shiftzoom.js?

Tags: javascript

The following code is an exctract of the shiftzoom.js (a javascript known library for zooming images)

```
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,r){e=function(c){return(c<62?'':e(parseInt(c/62)))+((c=c%62)>35?
String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if('0'.replace(0,e)==0){while(c--
)r[e(c)]=k[c];k=[function(e){return r[e]||e}];e=function(){return'([jA-DFH-KMO-RT-VX-Z]|[1-
8]\\w)'};c=1};while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);return p}('U 5F,23,1F,1C=1f,C={2x:1f,version:3.9,released:\'2011-12-13 00:00:00\',72:1c,73:1c,74:1c,76:J,5H:J,77:20,78:1f,5I:J,5J:J,79:J,7a:1c,7b:J,7c:J,7d:\'\',7
e:40,7f:90,7g:25,7h:75,7i:\'red\',7j:\'4w\',defaultOvborder:\'\',7k:\'\',7l:0,7m:50,7n:50,7
o:\'5K or 7q 5L 7r to 1u in\',7t:\'5K or 7q 5M 7r to 1u 2J\',7u:\'<dl><1y 
align="4x">Mouseover <7w>Keyboard Support<\\/7w><\\/1y><dt>7x in:<\\/dt><dd>[+] / [PgDn] / 
[End] <em>(is 5N)<\\/em> /<br \\/> [5L] + <u>Z</u> 3M 3y /<br \\/> double 5K + <u>Z</u> 3M 
3y /<br \\/><u>4V</u> / <u>5O</u> 3M 3y /<br \\/>3M 5O <u>7y</u><4W><br \\/><br \\/><\\/4W>
<\\/dd><dt>7x 2J:<\\/dt><dd>[–] / [PgUp] / [Home] <em>(is 5N)<\\/em> /<br \\/> [5M] + 
<u>Z</u> 3M 3y /<br \\/><u>4x</u> 3M 3y /<br \\/>3M 5O <u>up</u><4W><br \\/><br \\/><\\/4W>
<\\/dd><dt>Pan / Shift / Move:<\\/dt><dd>[Z] / [4x] / [7y] / [up] arrow 2b<br \\/>+ [5L] 
<em>(is 5N)</em> and + [5M] <em>(is slower)<\\/em><\\/dd>
<\\/dl>\',3N:"data:image/3N;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAJH/AP///wAAAP///wAAACH/C0FET0JFOklSMS4wAt7t
ACH5BAEAAAIALAAAAAABAAEAAAICVAEAOw==",add:17(V,11){17 4y(3c,4z){U 
47=3c;B(3c>8191&&3c<10485){3c=3c-
7A;47=H.1n(3c*H.4A(10,4z))/H.4A(10,4z);47=47+7A}M{47=H.1n(3c*H.4A(10,4z))/H.4A(10,4z)}19 
47}17 7B(){U 3c=5P.parse(3l 5P())+H.floor(H.random()*100000000000);19 3c.toString(16)}17 
48(){U bs=J,5R=J,5S=J,5T=J;4X{bs=(1g.3d.A.48!==3O)}4Y(e){}4X{5R=(1g.3d.A.4Z!==3O)}4Y(e)
{}4X{5S=(1g.3d.A.51!==3O)}4Y(e){}4X{5T=(1g.3d.A.52!==3O)}4Y(e){}19(bs||5R||5S||5T?
1c:J)}B(!V.7C){V.A.1m="1O";U 49=
{"1W":C.7k,"1q":C.7f,"3m":C.7e,"4a":C.7o,"4b":C.7t,"3n":C.7u,"5U":C.5H,"53":C.77,"1L":C.7g,
"3P":C.7h,"4c":C.7i,"3o":C.7j,"1u":C.7l,"3Q":C.7m,"3R":C.7n,"24":C.7d,"3S":C.78,"2R":C.5I,"
4B":C.5J};B(11){5V(U i in 49){B(!11[i])
{11[i]=49[i]}}}M{11=49}B(1g.images&&1g.7D&&1g.7E&&1g.54){U D,2g,18,I,1y=V.F,j=C.E(\'1y\'),3T=C.E(\'j\'),1Q=C.E(\'1y\'),map,mpn=V.useMap.7F("#");j.55=(V.Q!=""?V.Q:V.Q=7B());1y.1G(1Q);1Q.Q=j.55+\'_wrap\';1Q.1G(3T);1Q.1G(j);j.wrapid=1Q.Q;j.11=49;j.26=V.1p;B(V.5W&&V.5X){j.2n=4y(V.5W/V.K,4);j.5Y=4y(V.5X/V.O,4);j.1s=V.5W;j.1v=V.5X}M{2g=3l 5Z;2g.1p=V.1p;j.2n=4y(2g.K/V.K,4);j.5Y=4y(2g.O/V.O,4);j.1s=2g.K;j.1v=2g.O}B(V.K>=X&&V.K<=j.1s&&V.O>=X&&V.O<=j.1v){j.3z=(15 11[\'3z\']===\'2z\'?11[\'3z\']:C.72);j.2b=(15 11[\'2b\']===\'2z\'?11[\'2b\']:C.73);j.2c=(15 11[\'2c\']===\'2z\'?11[\'2c\']:C.76);j.2R=(15
 11[\'2R\']===\'2z\'?11[\'2R\']:C.5I);j.1H=(15 11[\'1H\']===\'2z\'?11[\'1H\']:C.74);j.1Z=
(15 11[\'1Z\']===\'2z\'?11[\'1Z\']:C.79);j.4d=(15 11[\'4d\']===\'2z\'?
11[\'4d\']:C.7b);j.3e=(15 11[\'3e\']===\'2z\'?11[\'3e\']:C.7a);j.3A=(15 
11[\'3A\']===\'2z\'?11[\'3A\']:C.7c);j.4B=(15 11[\'4B\']===\'2z\'?11[\'4B\']:C.5J);j.7G=(15
 11[\'5U\']===\'2z\'?11[\'5U\']:C.5H);j.24=(15 11[\'24\']===\'1t\'?
11[\'24\']:j.11[\'24\']);j.3S=(15 11[\'3S\']===\'61\'?11[\'3S\']:j.11[\'3S\']);j.2R=
(j.2R?"2R":"nearest-neighbor");j.1W=(15 11[\'1W\']===\'1t\'?11[\'1W\']:j.11[\'1W\']);j.4a=
(15 11[\'4a\']===\'1t\'?11[\'4a\']:j.11[\'4a\']);j.4b=(15 11[\'4b\']===\'1t\'?
11[\'4b\']:j.11[\'4b\']);j.3n=(15 11[\'3n\']===\'1t\'?
11[\'3n\']:j.11[\'3n\']);j.7H=j.3n;j.4c=(15 11[\'4c\']===\'1t\'?
11[\'4c\']:j.11[\'4c\']);j.3o=(15 11[\'3o\']===\'1t\'?11[\'3o\']:j.11[\'3o\']);j.62=(15
 11[\'53\']===\'2h\'?P(H.1h(H.1d(5,11[\'53\']),X)):j.11[\'53\']);j.1L=(15 
11[\'1L\']===\'2h\'?P(H.1h(H.1d(10,11[\'1L\']),50)):j.11[\'1L\'])/X;j.3m=(15 
11[\'3m\']===\'2h\'?P(H.1h(H.1d(5,11[\'3m\']),X)):j.11[\'3m\']);j.3P=(15 
11[\'3P\']===\'2h\'?P(H.1h(H.1d(0,11[\'3P\']),X)):j.11[\'3P\']);j.1q=(15 
11[\'1q\']===\'2h\'?P(H.1h(H.1d(0,11[\'1q\']),X)):j.11[\'1q\']);j.4C=(15 
411[\'4C\']===\'2h\'?P(H.1h(H.1d(0,11[\'4C\']),20)):H.1h(H.1n(V.K/X),H.1n(V.O/X)));j.1u=(15
 11[\'1u\']===\'2h\'?1S(H.1h(H.1d(0,11[\'1u\']),X)):j.11[\'1u\']);j.3Q=(15 
11[\'3Q\']===\'2h\'?1S(H.1h(H.1d(0,11[\'3Q\']),X)):j.11[\'3Q\']);j.3R=(15 11[\'3R\']===\'2h\'?1S(H.1h(H.1d(0,11[\'3R\']),X)):j.11[\'3R\']);j.11=1f;49=1f;j.bc="2o 4w 3B";j.dc="2o gray 3B";j.2i=J;j.4e=J;j.63=0;j.2j=J;j.2k=J;D=V.F.A;D.1D=(D.1D==\'static\'||D.1D==\'\'?\'56\':D.1D);D.O=V.O+\'R\';D.K=V.K+\'R\';D.57=\'1i\';D.64=\'1O\';D.4f=D.4g="2K";V.F.3p="on";D.2p="2K";1Q.Z=0;1Q.1a=0;1Q.K=V.K;1Q.O=V.O;1Q.3p="on";D=1Q.A;D.4f=D.4g="2K";D.1m="1O";D.2q="2u";D.1D="21";D.Z=\'1i\';D.1a=\'1i\';D.K=V.K+\'R\';D.O=V.O+\'R\';3T.Q=j.55+\'_img\';3T.1p=V.1p;D=3T.A;D.4D=j.2R;D.1D="21";D.Z=\'1i\';D.1a=\'1i\';D.K=\'X%\';D.O=\'X%\';j.58=3T.Q;j.3p="on";D=j.A;D.4f=D.4g=D.WebkitTouchCallout="2K";D.2q="2u";D.1D="56";B(1g.59&&!1l.3C&&(!1g.3D||1g.3D<9)){D.5a="2d(\'"+j.1W+"3U.3N\') 5b"}B(1g.59&&1g.3D&&1g.3D>=9){D.5a="2d("+C.3N+") 5b"}D.Z=\'1i\';D.1a=\'1i\';D.K=\'X%\';D.O=\'X%\';D.1b="1Y";j.3f=D.1b;j.Y=1Q.K;j.65=J;j.5c=0;j.1e=1Q.O;j.2r=j.1s-j.Y;j.2s=j.1v-j.1e;V.Q="";1Q.F.2Y(V);j.Q=j.55;j.7I=5d.66.4h(/android/i);j.7J=5d.platform.4h(/iPad|iPhone|iPod/i);j.7K=15(1g.7L)!="3O"?1c:J;j.7M=15(1g.7N)!="3O"?1c:J;j.28=j.7K&&(j.7J||j.7I||j.4B)?1c:J;B(j.28){j.2b=J;j.1Z=J}j.1o=1g.59&&!1l.3C&&(!1g.3D||1g.3D<9)?1:0;j.3g=1g.59&&1g.3D&&1g.3D>=9?1:0;j.7O=j.1o&&!1l.67?1:0;B(j.3z){B(j.1o){1Q.A.2l="2A(1q=0)"}M{1Q.A.1q=0}}1Q.A.1m=\'1I\';j.22=1l.atob!=3O&&!1l.7P&&!1l.3C?1:0;j.4i=!j.22&&5d.66.68(\'WebKit\')>-1?1:0;j.2L=5d.66.68(\'Gecko\')>-1&&1l.7P&&!1l.3C?1:0;j.7Q=1l.3C?1:0;j.69=48();j.1R=(j.1o&&(1g.7R==\'BackCompat\'||1g.7R==\'QuirksMode\')?1c:J);j.7C=1c;18=C.E(\'j\');18.1p=j.1o?1f:1f;18.A.2q=\'2K\';18.Q=j.Q+\'_isrc\';1y.1G(18);j.4E=18.Q;18=C.E(\'1y\');18.Q=j.Q+\'_xyco\';D=18.A;B(j.1o){D.2Z=\'2B\'}D.O=\'5e\';D.K=\'5e\';D.2q=\'2u\';D.1D=\'21\';D.Z=\'1i\';D.4F=\'1i\';D.4f=D.4g="2K";18.3p="on";B(j.3z&&j.1Z||!j.1Z){D.1m=\'1O\'}D.1b=\'7S\';1y.1G(18);j.3E=18.Q;B(!j.1o){I=C.E(\'1y\');D=I.A;D.O=\'X%\';D.K=\'X%\';D.Z=\'1i\';D.4F=\'1i\';D.1D=\'21\';D.2Z=\'2B\';D.1q=0.5;18.1G(I)}I=C.E(\'1y\');I.Q=j.Q+\'_cpos\';I.29="x:0 y:0";I.3p="on";D=I.A;D.6a=\'Z\';D.6b=\'4V\';D.Z=\'1i\';D.4F=\'1i\';D.1D=\'56\';D.2q=\'2u\';D.5f=\'4w\';D.31=\'5g\';D.6c=\'6d, 6e, 6f-6g\';D.6h=\'6i\';D.6j=\'6k\';D.7T=\'7U\';D.57=\'3F 3G\';D.6l=\'1i 1i 3G 2B\';18.1G(I);j.4G=I.Q;18=C.E(\'1y\');D=18.A;B(j.3z&&j.2b||!j.2b){D.1m=\'1O\'}18.Q=j.Q+\'_ctrl\';D.O=\'4H\';D.K=\'6m\';D.2q="2u";D.1D=\'21\';D.3r=\'2o\';D.31=\'2o\';D.2Z="#cccccc";B(j.1o){D.2l="2A(1q="+j.1q+")"}M{D.1q=j.1q/X}D.1b=\'3f\';D.Z=\'1i\';D.1a=\'1i\';B(j.22||j.69){D.48=D.4Z=D.51=D.52="1i 1i 4j 2B"}1y.1G(18);j.1E=18.Q;I=C.E(\'1y\');D=I.A;D.O=\'3F\';D.K=\'3F\';D.1D=\'21\';D.3r=\'2o\';D.31=\'2o\';D.Z=\'3G\';D.1a=\'3px\';D.2Z="2B";18.1G(I);I=C.E(\'1y\');D=I.A;D.O=\'7V\';D.K=\'3F\';D.1D=\'21\';D.3r=\'2o\';D.31=\'2o\';D.Z=\'3G\';D.1a=\'6n\';D.2Z="2B";18.1G(I);I=C.E(\'1y\');D=I.A;D.O=\'3F\';D.K=\'4j\';D.1D=\'21\';D.3r=\'2o\';D.31=\'2o\';D.Z=\'14px\';D.1a=\'6n\';D.2Z="2B";18.1G(I);I=C.E(\'1y\');D=I.A;D.O=\'4j\';D.K=\'3F\';D.1D=\'21\';D.3r=\'2o\';D.31=\'2o\';D.Z=\'17px\';D.1a=\'3G\';D.2Z="2B";18.1G(I);I=C.E(\'1y\');D=I.A;D.O=\'3F\';D.K=\'4j\';D.1D=\'21\';D.3r=\'2o\';D.31=\'2o\';D.Z=\'30px\';D.1a=\'6n\';D.2Z="2B";18.1G(I);I=C.E(\'1y\');I.Q=j.Q+\'_kbin\';D=I.A;D.O=(j.1R?16:14)+\'R\';D.1b=\'7S\';D.K=(j.1R?10:8)+\'R\';D.2q="2u";D.1D=\'21\';D.2p=j.bc;D.3V=j.dc;D.3W=j.dc;D.Z=\'1i\';D.1a=\'1i\';j.5h=j.Q+\'_ttip\';B(j.1o){I.4I=3l 5i(\'C.6o("\'+j.Q+\'");\');I.4J=3l 5i(\'C.6p("\'+j.Q+\'");\')}M{I.4k("4I","C.6o(\'"+j.Q+"\');");I.4k("4J","C.6p(\'"+j.Q+"\');")}18.1G(I);j.kbinid=I.Q;I=C.E(\'1y\');I.Q=j.Q+\'_zoin\';I.4K=j.4a;D=I.A;D.O=(j.1R?16:14)+\'R\';D.K=(j.1R?16:14)+\'R\';D.2q="2u";D.1D=\'21\';D.2p=j.bc;D.3V=j.dc;D.3W=j.dc;D.Z=\'5g\';D.1a=\'1i\';B(j.1o){I.4L=3l 5i(\'C.3X(1T,1,"\'+j.Q+\'");\')}M{I.4k("4L","C.3X(1T,1,\'"+j.Q+"\');")}18.1G(I);j.5j=I.Q;I=C.E(\'1y\');I.Q=j.Q+\'_zout\';I.4K=j.4b;D=I.A;D.O=(j.1R?16:14)+\'R\';D.K=(j.1R?16:14)+\'R\';D.2q="2u";D.1D=\'21\';D.2p=j.bc;D.3V=j.dc;D.3W=j.dc;D.Z=\'26px\';D.1a=\'1i\';B(j.1o){I.4L=3l 5i(\'C.3X(1T,0,"\'+j.Q+\'");\')}M{I.4k("4L","C.3X(1T,0,\'"+j.Q+"\');")}18.1G(I);j.5k=I.Q;18=C.E(\'1y\');18.Q=j.Q+\'_info\';D=18.A;D.1m=\'1O\';D.O=\'4H\';D.K=\'6q\';D.Z=(j.2b?\'6m\':\'1i\');D.1a=\'1i\';D.2q="2u";D.64=\'1O\';D.1D=\'21\';D.3r=\'4H\';D.31=\'5g\';D.6c=\'6d, 6e, 6f-6g\';D.6h=\'6i\';D.6j=\'6k\';D.6l=\'1i 1i 3G 2B\';D.5f="#7W";B(j.1o){D.2l="2A(1q=X)"}M{D.1q=1}D.1b=\'6r\';1y.1G(18);j.2O=18.Q;I=C.E(\'1y\');D=I.A;D.1D=\'21\';D.O=\'4H\';D.K=\'6q\';D.Z=\'1i\';D.1a=\'1i\';D.2q="2u";D.2Z="#000000";B(j.1o){D.2l="2A(1q=50)"}M{D.1q=0.50}18.1G(I);I=C.E(\'1y\');I.Q=j.Q+\'_text\';D=I.A;D.1D=\'21\';D.O=\'4H\';D.K=\'6q\';D.Z=\'1i\';D.1a=\'1i\';D.6a=\'center\';D.6b=\'4V\';D.64=\'1O\';D.2q="2u";D.5f="#7W";B(j.1o){D.2l="2A(1q=X)"}18.1G(I);j.2P=I.Q;I.29="X / "+P(j.2n*X)+" %";18=C.E(\'1y\');18.Q=j.Q+\'_over\';D=18.A;D.O=(1Q.O*j.1L)+\'R\';D.K=(1Q.K*j.1L)+\'R\';D.2q="2u";D.1D=\'21\';D.4F=\'1i\';D.4x=\'1i\';D.4l=j.4C+\'R 3B \'+j.3o;D.4m=j.4C+\'R 3B \'+j.3o;B(j.22||j.69){D.4l=\'1i 3B \'+j.3o;D.4m=\'1i 3B \'+j.3o;D.52=D.4Z=D.51=D.48="1i 1i 4j 2B"}D.4f=D.4g="2K";D.1m="1O";18.3p="on";1y.1G(18);I=C.E(\'j\');I.Q=j.Q+\'_tumb\';I.1p=3T.1p;D=I.A;D.O=(1Q.O*j.1L)+\'R\';D.K=(1Q.K*j.1L)+\'R\';D.2q="2u";D.1D=\'21\';D.4F=\'1i\';D.4x=\'1i\';D.4D=j.2R;18.1G(I);j.6s=I.Q;B(!j.28){I.4n=C.7X}I=C.E(\'1y\');I.Q=j.Q+\'_view\';I.2r=0;I.2s=0;D=I.A;D.3r=\'2o\';D.31=\'2o\';D.2q="2u";D.1D=\'21\';D.Z=\'1i\';D.1a=\'1i\';D.2p=\'2o 3B \'+j.4c;D.O=P((1Q.O*j.1L)-(j.1R?0:2))+\'R\';D.K=P((1Q.K*j.1L)-(j.1R?0:2))+\'R\';B(j.1o){D.5a="2d(\'"+j.1W+"3U.3N\') 5b";D.2l="2A(1q="+j.3P+")"}M{D.1q=j.3P/X}B(j.3g){D.5a="2d("+C.3N+") 5b"}18.1G(I);j.2e=18.Q;j.4o=I.Q;5F=17(){U j=C.G(1F);B(j){C.G(j.2P).29=P((j.F.K/j.Y)*X)+" / "+P(j.2n*X)+" %"}};B(j.28){j.7L=C.7Y;B(j.7M){j.7N=C.7Z}}M{I.4n=C.80;j.ondblclick=17(){C.3X(1T,1,j.Q,1c)};j.oncontextmenu=17(){19 J;C.3X(1T,0,j.Q,1c);19 J};j.4n=C.5l;j.4I=C.81;j.4J=C.82;B(j.1Z){j.2v=(j.3e?j.4d?C.6t:C.4M:j.3A?C.6u:C.5m)}}B(j.1u>0&&j.3z&&j.1H){j.1H=J;j.6v=1c}B(j.1u>0){C.83(j,j.1u)}B(j.3Q!=50||j.3R!=50){C.84(j,j.3Q+\'%\',j.3R+\'%\')}B(j.3S){C.85(j,j.3S)}B(j.3z){C.6w(j.Q,0)}}M{V.F.2Y(1Q);V.A.1m=\'1I\'}}M{V.A.1m=\'1I\'}}19 J},remove:17(j,v){B(j&&15(j.1E)==="1t"){U V,T=j.F.F;j.4n=1f;j.2v=1f;1g.2v=1f;1g.3s=1f;1g.6x=1f;1g.6y=1f;1g.6z=1f;B(j.2L){1l.86(\'6A\',C.4N,J)}M{1l.4O=1f}V=C.G(j.2e);B(V){T.2Y(V)}V=C.G(j.2O);B(V){T.2Y(V)}V=C.G(j.1E);B(V){T.2Y(V)}V=C.G(j.3E);B(V){T.2Y(V)}V=C.G(j.4E);B(V){T.2Y(V)}V=C.E(\'j\');V.Q=j.Q;j.Q="";j.1E=J;V.K=(v?j.1s:j.Y);V.O=(v?j.1v:j.1e);V.A.K=(v?j.1s:j.Y)+\'R\';V.A.O=(v?j.1v:j.1e)+\'R\';V.A.2p="1i 2K";V.A.1b="6r";V.1p=j.26;T.A.K=(v?j.1s:j.Y)+\'R\';T.A.O=(v?j.1v:j.1e)+\'R\';T.2Y(j.F);T.1G(V)}19 J},85:17(j,v){B(j&&15(v)==="61"&&15(j.1E)==="1t"){U i,d,x,y,w,h,p,q,r,t,g,s,z,m,n,oe,3a,ie,1U,V,l=v.2T;5V(i=0;i<l;i++){w=v[i].w||0;h=v[i].h||0;s=v[i].1p||0;q=v[i].noscale||0;d=v[i].Q||0;B(d){V=C.G(d)}M{V=J}B(!V&&w>=8&&h>=8&&s!=\'\'){x=H.1r(v[i].x)||0;y=H.1r(v[i].y)||0;p=H.1d(H.1h(H.1r(v[i].pos),9),0)||0;z=v[i].src2||0;r=v[i].87||0;t=v[i].4K||0;g=v[i].4p||0;oe=C.E(\'a\');3a=oe.A;B(d){oe.Q=d}B(r){oe.87=r}B(g){oe.4p=g}oe.3p="on";3a.2p="1i 2K";3a.31="1i";3a.3r="1i";3a.6B="1i";3a.57="1i";3a.textDecoration="2K";3a.88=3a.89=3a.8a="2K";j.1G(oe);ie=C.E(\'j\');1U=ie.A;B(j.7O){ie.1p=j.1W+"3U.3N";ie.A.2l="6C:6D.6E.6F(1p=\'"+s+"\', 6G=\'5n\')"}M{ie.1p=s}ie.K=w;ie.O=h;B(t){ie.4K=t}ie.3p="on";1U.1D="21";1U.6B="1i";1U.57="1i";1U.2p="1i 2K";1U.K=q?w+\'R\':(w/(j.1s/X))+\'%\';1U.O=q?h+\'R\':(h/(j.1v/X))+\'%\';n=(j.1v/X);m=(j.1s/X);B(q){1U.1a=(y?y/n:0)+\'%\';1U.Z=(x?x/m:0)+\'%\'}M{B(!p||p==4||p==5||p==6){1U.1a=((y?y/n:0)-(1S(1U.O)/2))+\'%\'}M B(p==7||p==8||p==9){1U.1a=((y?y/n:0)-1S(1U.O))+\'%\'}M B(p==1||p==2||p==3){1U.1a=(y?y/n:0)+\'%\'}B(!p||p==2||p==5||p==8){1U.Z=((x?x/m:0)-(1S(1U.K)/2))+\'%\'}M B(p==3||p==6||p==9){1U.Z=((x?x/m:0)-1S(1U.K))+\'%\'}M B(p==1||p==4||p==7){1U.Z=(x?x/m:0)+\'%\'}}1U.88=1U.89=1U.8a="2K";1U.4D=j.2R;B(z){ie.5o=s;ie.5p=z;B(!j.1o){ie.4k("4I","1T.1p=1T.5p;");ie.4k("4J","1T.1p=1T.5o;")}}oe.1G(ie);B(z&&j.1o){oe.4I=C.8b;oe.4J=C.8c}}}}19 J},destruct:17(j,v){B(j&&v&&15(j.1E)==="1t"){B(15(v)==="1t"){U V=C.G(v);B(V){j.2Y(V)}}B(15(v)==="2z"){j.29=""}}19 J},84:17(j,x,y){B(j&&15(j.1E)==="1t"){B(j.F.K>j.Y||j.F.O>j.1e){17 6H(m,i,n){U d=1S(m);B(d>n){d=n}M B(d<i){d=i}19 d}U f,h,v,q=1S((j.F.K-j.Y)/(j.1s-j.Y));B(15(x)=="1t"){B(x.4h(/^([+-])?\\d*([\\.])?\\d*$/)){f=(6H(x,-3Y,3Y)*-1)+3Y;x=f*(((j.1s-j.Y)*q)/6I);h=(0.5-(f/6I))*j.Y;x=x-h}M B(x.4h(/^\\d*([\\.])?\\d*([%]){1,1}$/)){x=((j.1s-j.Y)*q)*(1S(x)/X)}M{x=0}}M{x=(x-(j.Y/2))*q}B(15(y)=="1t"){B(y.4h(/^([+-])?\\d*([\\.])?\\d*$/)){f=(6H(y,-90,90)*-1)+90;y=f*(((j.1v-j.1e)*q)/3Y);v=(0.5-(f/3Y))*j.1e;y=y-v}M B(y.4h(/^\\d*([\\.])?\\d*([%]){1,1}$/)){y=((j.1v-j.1e)*q)*(1S(y)/X)}M{y=0}}M{y=(y-(j.1e/2))*q}h=H.1d(0,H.1h(j.2r,x||0));v=H.1d(0,H.1h(j.2s,y||0));j.F.A.Z=(h*-1)+\'R\';j.F.A.1a=(v*-1)+\'R\';j.F.Z=(h*-1);j.F.1a=(v*-1);B(j.1H){U I=C.G(j.4o).A;I.Z=H.1n((H.1r(P(j.F.A.Z,10))/(j.F.K/j.Y))*j.1L)-(j.1R?2:0)+\'R\';I.1a=H.1n((H.1r(P(j.F.A.1a,10))/(j.F.O/j.1e))*j.1L)-(j.1R?2:0)+\'R\'}}}19 J},83:17(j,v){B(j&&15(j.1E)==="1t"){B(15(v)==="2h"){U mw,mh,mx,my,f;v=H.1d(0,H.1h(X,1S(v)));f=v>0?v/X:0;mw=H.1n(f*(j.1s-j.Y))+j.Y;mh=H.1n(f*(j.1v-j.1e))+j.1e;mx=H.1n((mw/2)-(j.Y/2))*-1;my=H.1n((mh/2)-(j.1e/2))*-1;j.F.A.K=mw+\'R\';j.F.A.O=mh+\'R\';j.F.A.Z=mx+\'R\';j.F.A.1a=my+\'R\';j.F.K=mw;j.F.O=mh;j.F.Z=mx;j.F.1a=my;j.2r=j.F.K-j.Y;j.2s=j.F.O-j.1e;B(j.F.K>j.Y||j.F.O>j.1e){B(j.1o){j.A.1b="2d(\'"+j.1W+"4q.2D\'),2E"}M{j.A.1b="2E"}B(j.1H){C.3H(j);C.G(j.2e).A.1m="1I"}}M{j.A.1b="1Y";B(j.1H){C.G(j.2e).A.1m="1O"}}}}19 J},4r:17(j,T){B(j&&15(j.1E)==="1t"){17 5q(v){B(15(v)==="2h"){v=H.1d(0,H.1h(X,1S(v)))}M{v=0.5}19 v};U io=J,x=T[0],y=T[1],z=T[2],p=T[3]||J,s=T[4]||J,d=T[5]||J,b=T[6]||J,a=T[7]||J;B(15(p)==="2h"){B(p==3){io=1c}M B(p==0){p=1}M{p=H.1d(0,H.1h(2,1S(p)))}}M{p=1}B(15(s)==="2h"){s=H.1d(10,H.1h(X,P(s)))}B(15(d)==="2h"){d=H.1d(10,H.1h(X,P(d)))}M{d=30}U fz,mz,ix,iy,wf,hf,sw,sh,sx,sy,ew,eh,ex,ey;x=5q(x);y=5q(y);z=5q(z);fz=z*0.01;B(j.24&&j.26){C.3b(j,j.24,J,1c)}j.2j=J;j.2k=J;B(j.F.K>j.Y||j.F.O>j.1e){B(j.1o){j.A.1b="2d(\'"+j.1W+"4q.2D\'),2E"}M{j.A.1b="2E"}}M{j.A.1b="1Y"}ix=(j.1s-j.Y)*(x*0.01);iy=(j.1v-j.1e)*(y*0.01);sw=P(j.F.A.K,10);sh=P(j.F.A.O,10);sx=P(j.F.A.Z,10);sy=P(j.F.A.1a,10);ew=z>-1?H.1n(fz*(j.1s-j.Y))+j.Y:sw;eh=z>-1?H.1n(fz*(j.1v-j.1e))+j.1e:sh;wf=1S((ew-j.Y)/(j.1s-j.Y));hf=1S((eh-j.1e)/(j.1v-j.1e));ex=H.1d(0,H.1h(ew-j.Y,ix*wf))*-1;ey=H.1d(0,H.1h(eh-j.1e,iy*hf))*-1;B(15(s)!=="2h"){mz=H.1r(H.1r(ex)-H.1r(sx));mz=H.1d(mz,H.1r(H.1r(ey)-H.1r(sy)));mz=H.1d(mz,H.1r(H.1r(ew)-H.1r(sw)));mz=H.1d(mz,H.1r(H.1r(eh)-H.1r(sh)));s=H.1n(mz/d)}B(j.3h){1l.2w(j.3h)}U mx,my,mw,mh,q=0,c=0,t=H.1d(5,s),k=1/t;j.3h=1l.3I(17(){q=io?((-H.cos((k*c)*H.PI)/2)+0.5)||0:H.4A((k*c),p)||0;mw=H.5s(sw+(q*(ew-sw)));mh=H.5s(sh+(q*(eh-sh)));mx=H.5s(sx+(q*(ex-sx)));my=H.5s(sy+(q*(ey-sy)));j.F.A.K=mw+\'R\';j.F.A.O=mh+\'R\';j.F.A.Z=mx+\'R\';j.F.A.1a=my+\'R\';j.F.K=mw;j.F.O=mh;j.F.Z=mx;j.F.1a=my;B(j.4i){j.F.2m.A.K=mw+\'R\';j.F.2m.A.O=mh+\'R\'}c++;B(c>t){1l.2w(j.3h);j.2r=j.F.K-j.Y;j.2s=j.F.O-j.1e;j.2j=J;j.2k=J;B(j.24&&j.26){C.3b(j,j.26,J,1c)}B(j.F.K>j.Y||j.F.O>j.1e){B(j.1o){j.A.1b="2d(\'"+j.1W+"4q.2D\'),2E"}M{j.A.1b="2E"}B(j.1H){C.3H(j);C.G(j.2e).A.1m="1I"}}M{j.A.1b="1Y";B(j.1H){C.G(j.2e).A.1m="1O"}}B(j.2i){B(b&&15(b)==="1t"&&6P(\'15 \'+b)=="17"){1l.3i("1l[\'"+b+"\'](\'"+(15(a)==\'2h\'||15(a)==\'1t\'?a:\'\')+"\')",30)}1l.3i("C.8d(C.G(\'"+j.Q+"\'))",j.63+1000)}M{B(b&&15(b)==="1t"&&6P(\'15 \'+b)=="17"){1l.3i("1l[\'"+b+"\'](\'"+(15(a)==\'2h\'||15(a)==\'1t\'?a:\'\')+"\')",8e)}}}},d)}19 J},play:17(j,d,l,T,c){B(j&&15(j.1E)==="1t"){B(!j.2i&&15(d)==="2h"&&15(l)==="2z"&&15(T)==="61"){B(T.2T>=1){U n=0,mx=3,t=T.2T,i;5V(i=0;i<t;++i){n=H.1d(0,T[i].2T);mx=n<mx?n:mx}j.6Q=(c&&15(c)==="1t"&&6P(\'15 \'+c)=="17"?c:0);B(mx>=3){j.3J=T;j.2M=0;j.2i=1c;j.4e=l;j.63=H.1r(d);j.2c=1c;B(j.1H){C.5t(j,\'1H\',J)}B(j.2b&&!j.28){C.5t(j,\'2b\',J)}B(j.1Z&&!j.28){C.5t(j,\'1Z\',J)}C.4r(C.G(j.Q),j.3J[j.2M])}}}}19 J},4s:17(j){B(j&&15(j.1E)==="1t"){B(j.2i){j.2i=J;B(j.3h){1l.2w(j.3h)}j.4e=J;j.2M=0;j.2r=j.F.K-j.Y;j.2s=j.F.O-j.1e;B(j.24&&j.26){C.3b(j,j.26,J,1c)}B(j.F.K>j.Y||j.F.O>j.1e){B(j.1o){j.A.1b="2d(\'"+j.1W+"4q.2D\'),2E"}M{j.A.1b="2E"}B(j.1H){C.3H(j);C.G(j.2e).A.1m="1I"}}M{j.A.1b="1Y";B(j.1H){C.G(j.2e).A.1m="1O"}}B(j.6Q){1l.3i("1l[\'"+j.6Q+"\']()",8e)}}}19 J},3b:17(j,1p,v,z){B(j&&15(j.1E)==="1t"){B(15(1p)==="1t"&&15(v)==="2z"){U 2g=3l 5Z();C.G(j.58);2g.4P=17(){C.G(j.1E).A.1m="1O";C.G(j.2e).A.1m="1O";C.G(j.3E).A.1m="1O";B(v==1c){C.G(j.4E).1p=2g.1p;B(!z){B(j.1o){2g.4P=\'\';2g=1f}6R 2g}C.6S(j.Q,X)}M B(v==J){U T=C.G(j.58);T.1p=2g.1p;T.A.4D=j.2R;B(!z){C.G(j.6s).1p=T.1p;B(j.26!=T.1p){j.26=T.1p}B(j.1o){2g.4P=\'\';2g=1f}6R 2g}B(j.2b&&!j.28){C.G(j.1E).A.1m="1I"}B(j.1H&&(j.F.K>j.Y||j.F.O>j.1e)){C.G(j.2e).A.1m="1I"}B(j.1Z&&!j.28){C.G(j.3E).A.1m="1I"}}};2g.1p=1p}}19 J},lowsource:17(j,1p){B(j&&15(j.1E)==="1t"){B(15(1p)==="1t"&&!j.2i&&!j.2j&&!j.2k){U 3Z=3l 5Z();3Z.4P=17(){j.24=3Z.1p;B(j.1o){3Z.4P=\'\';3Z=1f}6R 3Z};3Z.1p=1p}}19 J},info:17(j,v){B(j&&15(j.1E)==="1t"){B(v&&15(v)==="1t"){j.3n=v}M{j.3n=j.7H}}19 J},5t:17(j,d,v){B(j&&15(j.1E)==="1t"){B(d&&15(v)==="2z"){8f(d.3K()){2f\'1H\':B(v==J&&j.1H==1c){C.G(j.2e).A.1m="1O"}M B(v==1c&&j.1H==J){B(j.F.K>j.Y||j.F.O>j.1e){C.3H(j);C.G(j.2e).A.1m="1I"}M{C.G(j.2e).A.1m="1O"}}j.1H=v;2t;2f\'1Z\':B(v==J&&j.1Z==1c){j.2v=1f;C.G(j.3E).A.1m="1O"}M B(v==1c&&j.1Z==J&&!j.28){C.G(j.3E).A.1m="1I";j.2v=C.4M}j.1Z=v;2t;2f\'4d\':B(v==J&&j.3e==1c&&j.1Z==1c&&!j.28){j.2v=C.4M}M B(v==1c&&j.3e==1c&&j.1Z==1c&&!j.28){j.2v=C.6t}j.4d=v;2t;2f\'3e\':B(v==J&&j.3e==1c&&j.1Z==1c&&!j.28){j.2v=C.5m}M B(v==1c&&j.3e==J&&j.1Z==1c&&!j.28){j.2v=C.4M}j.3e=v;2t;2f\'3A\':B(v==J&&j.3A==1c&&j.1Z==1c&&!j.28){j.2v=C.5m}M B(v==1c&&j.3A==J&&j.1Z==1c&&!j.28){j.2v=C.6u}j.3A=v;2t;2f\'2b\':B(v==J&&j.2b==1c){C.G(j.1E).A.1m="1O";C.G(j.2O).A.Z=\'1i\'}M B(v==1c&&j.2b==J&&!j.28){C.G(j.2O).A.Z=\'6m\';C.G(j.1E).A.1m="1I"}j.2b=v;2t;2f\'2j\':B(!j.2c&&!j.2b&&(P(j.F.A.K,10)<j.1s||P(j.F.A.O,10)<j.1v)){B(v==1c){j.2j=1c;j.2k=J;B(j.2L){j.A.1b="-3u-1u-in"}M B(j.22){j.A.1b="-22-1u-in"}M B(j.1o||j.3g){j.A.1b="2d(\'"+j.1W+"1u-in.2D\'),1Y"}M{j.A.1b="1Y"}}M{j.2j=J}}2t;2f\'2k\':B(!j.2c&&!j.2b&&(P(j.F.A.K,10)>j.Y||P(j.F.A.O,10)>j.1e)){B(v==1c){j.2k=1c;j.2j=J;B(j.2L){j.A.1b="-3u-1u-2J"}M B(j.22){j.A.1b="-22-1u-2J"}M B(j.1o||j.3g){j.A.1b="2d(\'"+j.1W+"1u-2J.2D\'),1Y"}M{j.A.1b="1Y"}}M{j.2k=J}}2t;2f\'2c\':j.2c=v;2t}}}19 J},5u:17(j,d){B(j&&d&&15(j.1E)==="1t"){B(d.3K()=="maxzoomx"){19 j.2n}M B(d.3K()=="maxzoomy"){19 j.5Y}M B(d.3K()=="1s"){19 j.1s}M B(d.3K()=="1v"){19 j.1v}M B(d.3K()=="playing"){19 j.2i}M B(d.3K()=="5v"){U q=1S((j.F.K-j.Y)/(j.1s-j.Y)),z=H.1h(H.1d(q*X,0),X)||0;U x=H.1h(H.1d(((H.1r(1S(j.F.A.Z))/((j.1s-j.Y)*q))*X),0),X)||0;U y=H.1h(H.1d(((H.1r(1S(j.F.A.1a))/((j.1v-j.1e)*q))*X),0),X)||0;19{x:x,y:y,z:z}}}19 J},G:17(v){19(1g.7E(v))},E:17(v){19(1g.7D(v))},L:17(s,v){s=s!=""?s.3K():\'8g\';B(1l.3C&&1l.3C.8h){1l.3C.8h(s.8i()+\': \'+v)}M B(1l.5w){B(!1l.5w[s]){1l.5w.8g(s+\': \'+v)}M{1l.5w[s](v)}}M{1l.1g.4K=s.8i()+\': \'+v}19 J},8d:17(j){B(j&&15(j.1E)==="1t"){B(j.2i){B(j.4e&&j.2M<(j.3J.2T-1)){j.2M=j.2M+1}M B(j.4e&&j.2M>=(j.3J.2T-1)){j.2M=0}M B(!j.4e&&j.2M<(j.3J.2T-1)){j.2M=j.2M+1}M{j.2M=j.3J.2T}B(j.2M<j.3J.2T){C.4r(C.G(j.Q),j.3J[j.2M])}M{C.4s(j)}}}19 J},3H:17(j){U I=C.G(j.4o);I.A.K=(H.1n((j.1L*j.Y)/(j.F.K/j.Y))-(j.1R?0:2))+\'R\';I.A.O=(H.1n((j.1L*j.1e)/(j.F.O/j.1e))-(j.1R?0:2))+\'R\';I.A.Z=H.1n((H.1r(j.F.Z)/(j.F.K/j.Y))*j.1L)-(j.1R?2:0)+\'R\';I.A.1a=H.1n((H.1r(j.F.1a)/(j.F.O/j.1e))*j.1L)-(j.1R?2:0)+\'R\';I.2r=(j.Y*j.1L)-(j.1R?0:2)-P(I.A.K,10);I.2s=(j.1e*j.1L)-(j.1R?0:2)-P(I.A.O,10);19 J},3v:17(V){U t,d={x:V.offsetLeft,y:V.offsetTop};B(V.8j){t=C.3v(V.8j);d.x+=t.x;d.y+=t.y}19 d},41:17(ex,ey,R,py){U ox,oy,k={ox:0,oy:0,ex:ex,ey:ey};B(5x.8k||5x.8l){ox=5x.8k;B(ox>0&&R==ex){ex-=ox}oy=5x.8l;B(oy>0&&py==ey){ey-=oy}}M B(1g.6T){ox=1g.6T.8m;oy=1g.6T.8n}M B(1g.3d){ox=1g.3d.8m;oy=1g.3d.8n}k.ox=ox;k.oy=oy;k.ex=ex;k.ey=ey;19 k},4M:17(e){B(1F!=1f){U k,t,x,y,ex,ey,R=0,py=0,o=C.G(1F),w=o.F.K,h=o.F.O;e=e?e:1l.3j;ex=e.2H;ey=e.2I;B(e.2U||e.2V){R=e.2U;py=e.2V}k=C.41(ex,ey,R,py);t=C.3v(o);x=H.1h(H.1d(k.ex+k.ox-t.x,0),w);y=H.1h(H.1d(k.ey+k.oy-t.y,0),h);C.G(o.4G).29=\'<3L>x:\'+x+\' y:\'+y+\'<\\/3L>\'}19 J},6t:17(e){B(1F!=1f){U k,t,x,y,z,ex,ey,R=0,py=0,o=C.G(1F),w=o.F.K,h=o.F.O;e=e?e:1l.3j;ex=e.2H;ey=e.2I;B(e.2U||e.2V){R=e.2U;py=e.2V}k=C.41(ex,ey,R,py);t=C.3v(o);z=(o.Y/w)*o.2n;x=P((H.1h(H.1d(k.ex+k.ox-t.x,0),w)*z),10);y=P((H.1h(H.1d(k.ey+k.oy-t.y,0),h)*z),10);C.G(o.4G).29=\'<3L>x:\'+x+\' y:\'+y+\'<\\/3L>\'}19 J},6u:17(e){B(1F!=1f){U k,t,x,y,z,ex,ey,R=0,py=0,na=!Number.prototype.5z?0:1,o=C.G(1F),w=o.F.K,h=o.F.O;e=e?e:1l.3j;ex=e.2H;ey=e.2I;B(e.2U||e.2V){R=e.2U;py=e.2V}k=C.41(ex,ey,R,py);t=C.3v(o);x=1S((H.1h(H.1d(k.ex+k.ox-t.x,0.0),w)/w)*X);x=na?x.5z(2):P(x);y=1S((H.1h(H.1d(k.ey+k.oy-t.y,0.0),h)/h)*X);y=na?y.5z(2):P(y);z=1S(((w-o.Y)/(o.1s-o.Y))*X);z=na?z.5z(2):P(z);C.G(o.4G).29=\'<3L>x:\'+x+\'% y:\'+y+\'% z:\'+z+\'%<\\/3L>\'}19 J},5m:17(e){B(1F!=1f){U k,t,x,y,42,43,ex,ey,R=0,py=0,o=C.G(1F),w=o.F.K,h=o.F.O;17 6U(v,n){U d,m,s;d=P(v);m=H.1r(1S(v-d)*60);s=H.1r(1S(P(m)-m)*60);19 H.1r(d)+"°"+P(m)+"\'"+P(s)+"\'\' "+n};e=e?e:1l.3j;ex=e.2H;ey=e.2I;B(e.2U||e.2V){R=e.2U;py=e.2V}k=C.41(ex,ey,R,py);t=C.3v(o);x=H.1h(H.1d(k.ex+k.ox-t.x,0),w);y=H.1h(H.1d(k.ey+k.oy-t.y,0),h);43=(x*6I/w)-3Y;42=90-(y*3Y/h);43=6U(43,43!=0?(43<0?"W":"E"):"");42=6U(42,42!=0?(42<0?"S":"N"):"");C.G(o.4G).29=\'<3L>Lat: \'+42+\' &bull; Lon: \'+43+\'<\\/3L>\'}19 J},6p:17(Q){U 4t,j=C.G(Q);4t=C.G(j.5h);B(4t){1g.54("3d")[0].2Y(4t)}19 J},6o:17(Q,xx,yy){xx=xx||0;yy=yy||0;U 18,I,j=C.G(Q),4t=C.G(j.5h);B(!4t){U t=C.3v(j.F.F);18=C.E(\'1y\');B(j.1o){18.A.2Z=\'2B\'}18.Q=j.5h;18.A.O=\'5e\';18.A.K=\'5e\';18.A.2q=\'2u\';18.A.1D=\'21\';18.A.2l="2A(1q=0)";18.A.1q=0;18.A.Z=(t.x+10+xx)+\'R\';18.A.1a=(t.y+yy)+\'R\';18.A.1m=\'1I\';18.A.2p=\'3B 3F 4w\';18.A.8o=18.A.8p=18.A.8q=18.A.8r=\'7V\';18.3p="on";18.A.4Z=18.A.52=18.A.51=18.A.48=\'1i 1i 4j 2B
```

i know that it's a javascript file but it looks very strange for me and i cannot understand anything from it, i'm just so curious about what is this kind of JS programming ?

Comment: Tada http://dean.edwards.name/packer/

Comment: is the compression different of the minification in JS ?

Comment: Basically they are the same things. The main purpose is to preserve bandwidth by making the javascript smaller and as an additional benefit making it a little harder to steal and reverse engineer the original source code.